# Hide div if nav is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple page with the standard bootstrap nav which collapses when on small screen. Right below the nav I have a div which I do not want to show if the `li` has `CSS` class `dropdown open`. Is it possible to do this via `CSS` only or do I have to go down the `jQuery/Javascript` route?

```
.navbar-nav > li.dropdown.open {
 /*How can I hide the div class="inner-details" here*/   
}
```

Comment: If the div is inside, yes, if not, no....

Comment: @epascarello the div is not inside `navbar-nav`

Comment: Than you will need to use JavaScript

Comment: CSS has no parent selector, so than no like @epascarello said..

Comment: @epascarello oh ok. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dropdown element is not wrapped with another one, you could possibly use the adjecent sibling selector like this:

```
li.dropdown.open + .inner-details {
    display: none;
}
```

Otherwise you could do tricks with negative margin and z-index, effectively sliding content from below the dropdown behind it, but really this will lead to messy layout.

There's no evil in using JavaScript. Bootstrap itself uses it for the navigation if I remember correctly.

Comment: I've got no issue with using `JS` I just thought if I can do with css then why not. Thanks for your answer